# Tf frames of a mobile robot

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, frame, transforms

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on mobile robot which has kinect mounted on it with an IMU unit.

I am confused about the frames of various types..Considering the above example please tell me what are the following frames.

1. Map frame
2. Odom frame
3. Base frame.

i know that the transformation between the kinect and base frame would be equal to the vector which should be added to base frame to get kinect frame...

Now i dont understand is what is Odom frame and what is the /tf between kinect and odom frame and how is it generated.. is it IMU readings or the Slam output pose for instance as in Gmapping.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50016/tf-frames-of-a-mobile-robot/) by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 263 on 2012-12-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should read [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF) and then [this proposal (REP 105)](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html). The proposal lists the differences and meanings of the most important frames (/map, /odom, /base_link).

In your setup the IMU would be responsible for the generation of the /odom -> /base_link transform.

Edit: Damn, too slow again. :D

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You want [REP 105](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html).

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-12-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2